# Forcing a login script to prompt for credentials?

Tags: login, credentials, share-credentials, login-items, net-use

**Scenario:**  Office is transferring from one server to another, on a different domain than is currently being used.  Net use login scripts fail automatically due to improper authentication.

**What I need** A login script to map drives to the new server, using different credentials than what the user logs in with.  Cannot put username and password for each user in the login script, it needs to prompt and allow a user to modify the domain/username and password to gain access to it.

**What it would look like**  Login script runs, opens a window prompting for the user to input alternative credentials, user inputs required credentials, drive maps properly.

I have done some google searches, and looked into vbs net use scripting, but it looks like it all requires the user's username and password to be put into the specific login batch file.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With VBS scripting, you could use something like

```
$username = InputBox("Type your username", vbOKOnly)
$password = InputBox("Type your password", vbOKOnly)
```

Comment: Would you mind elaborating a bit more on the syntax, possibly provide an example using something like Contoso?

Comment: @francisswest Unfortunately, I don't know what Contoso is. Basically, setup a variable (i.e. `$username` and `$password`), and the output of the InputBox will be put into that variable. You can then use $**variable** in your script, so that the Username and Password are not hard-coded. The part between the quotation marks is the message that comes up, the vbOKOnly part makes only an OK button appear on the dialog. The dialog will ask the question and provide 1 text field

Comment: No problem, Contoso is one of Microsoft's fictitious companies that it uses in examples while teaching how to do something.  So instead of using a domain name that actually exists (if you dont want your domain name to be published necessarily, you could rig up an example using Contoso.  I.e. Domain=sales.contoso.com (then the user plugs in the actual domain to get a working script)

Either way, the information you have provided looks extremely promising.  I will run it by the sysadmin and see what he thinks about it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how you would do that in [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/). This will prompt for credentials and then persistently map a drive based on those credentials.

```
#include <GuiConstants.au3>
#include <EditConstants.au3>

$gui = GuiCreate("Authenticate",120,170)

GUICtrlCreateLabel("Username:",10,10,50,20)
$username = GUICtrlCreateInput("",10,35,100,20)
GUICtrlCreateLabel("Password:",10,70,50,20)
$password = GUICtrlCreateInput("",10,95,100,20,$ES_PASSWORD)

$go = GuiCtrlCreateButton("OK",10,130,50,25)
$cancel = GuiCtrlCreateButton("Cancel",60,130,50,25)

GUISetState()
Do
    $msg = GUIGetMsg()

    If $msg = $go Then
        DriveMapAdd ("K:","//path/to/share",1,$username,$password)
    EndIf

    If $msg = $cancel Then
        Exit
    EndIf

Until GUIGetMsg() = $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
GuiDelete($gui)
```